# About the inverse and norm of a special sparse matrix

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, inverse

Let $r < n^2$, denote by $I_n$ the $n \times n$ identity matrix and consider the block matrix

$$A = \left[
\begin{array}{cccccc}
    0 & I_n & I_n & \ldots & I_n & I_n\\
    I_n & 0 & I_n & \ldots & I_n & I_n\\
    I_n & I_n & 0 & \ldots & I_n & I_n\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots\\
    I_n & I_n & I_n & \ldots & I_n & 0\\
\end{array} \right]$$
composed by $r \times r$ blocks. The zeros in the matrix represents a $n \times n$ block matrix filled with zeros.

Note the pattern, each block matrix in the diagonal of $A$ is a $n \times n$ zero matrix and the other blocks are identities. I'm interested in computing or at least bounding (by above) the norm

$$\left\| \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
   0 & A & A\\
   A & 0 & A\\
   A & A & 0\\
\end{array}\right]^{-1} \right\|$$ 
where each zero now is a $rn \times rn$ block matrix filled with zeros.

For some values for $r,n$ I tested, this matrix was invertible. I suspect it always is the case, but can't prove. I need a help to prove this and to bound this norm, which can be the usual spectral norm or the Frobenius norm.

Thank you very much.

**PS:** The condition $r < n^2$ comes from the original problem which lead me to this matrix. You can ignore it if not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbf1_k=(1,1,\ldots,1)^T\in\mathbb R^k$ denotes the $k$-vector of ones. Your block matrix is just $(\mathbf1_3\mathbf1_3^T-I_3)\otimes (\mathbf1_r\mathbf1_r^T-I_r)\otimes I_n$. Hence its inverse is $(\frac12\mathbf1_3\mathbf1_3^T-I_3)\otimes (\frac1{r-1}\mathbf1_r\mathbf1_r^T-I_r)\otimes I_n$ when $r>1$ and the spectral norm of this inverse is $1$.

Comment: Just amazing! I need to learn how to work like this. Could you just clarify how the norm is 1? Thanks.

Comment: In fact I manage to compute the inverse in a very different way and I find that the inverse is $$\frac{1}{2}\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
   -A^{-1} & A^{-1} & A^{-1}\\
   A^{-1} & -A^{-1} & A^{-1}\\
   A^{-1} & A^{-1} & -A^{-1}\\
\end{array}\right]$$
where $$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{r-1}\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
   -(r-2)I & I &\ldots & I\\
   I & -(r-2) & \ldots & I\\
   I & I & \ldots & -(r-2)I\\
\end{array}\right].$$

I am happy to see my matrix look like your answer, although I can't say if it agrees. Still have to convert the tensor notation to something simpler for me.

Comment: @Integral Yes, the expression you get is the one in my answer. The  spectral norm of a symmetric matrix is the spectral radius. In general, the spectral radius of a Kronecker product is the product of the spectral radii of the constituent multiplicands. The eigenvalues of $\mathbf 1_k\mathbf 1_k^T$ are a simple eigenvalue $k$ and $k-1$ zero eigenvalues. Hence the spectrum of $(\mathbf 1_k\mathbf 1_k^T-I_k)^{-1}$ consists of a $\frac1{k-1}$ and $k-1$ copies of $-1$. It follows that the spectral radius for your block inverse matrix is $1\times1\times1=1$.